# Jquery Fade Out on RollOut

Tags: jquery, colors, jquery-animate

The Jquery script below has two background colors set to initiate on rollover and rollout respectively. Is there a way to have the rollover color just fade away on rollout rather than fadein another color?

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    //Set the anchor link opacity to 0 and begin hover function
    $("#menu-sample-menu li").hover(function () {

         $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor:'#3333CC'}, 300);

        //On mouse-off
    }, function () {

     $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor:'#000000'}, 200);

    });
});
```

HTML

```
<nav id="access">
    <ul id="menu-sample-menu" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-198" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-198"><a href="http://www.threecell.com/demo/category/health-care-professional/">Health Care Professional</a>

        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-197" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-197"><a href="http://www.threecell.com/demo/category/web-designer/">Web Designer</a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-199" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-199"><a href="http://www.threecell.com/demo/category/construction-worker/">Construction Worker</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Style

```
#access {
    padding:0 20px;
    background:#111;
    box-shadow:0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

#access ul {
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:600;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

#access li {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#access ul li:first-child {
    padding-left:0;
}

#access a {
    display:block;
    padding:15px 24px;
    color:#f0f0f0;
    text-decoration:none;

}

#menu-sample-menu li {
    color: black;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #777;
    background-color: green;
    padding: 0 12px 0 12px;
}

#menu-sample-menu li a.hover {
    background: orange;
}


#access li.current_page_item > a,
#access li.current-menu-item > a {
    background: orange;
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#access a span {
    color:#999;
    font-size:11px;
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height:1.62em;
    text-transform:none;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could animate it back to its initial green color? http://jsfiddle.net/2LSN9/4/

Comment: Hey Stano, thx for the response. I considered just making the rollout color the same as the menu background color. However, it seemed redundant and I figured there was a better way to do it (as in just fade out the opacity of the over state leaving the background color to show)